# UItextview Write in multiple color in (real time) with NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uicolor

I have one Uitextview

i have one code like this in Text String color **Purple**

```
 let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple]

            let titleString = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World", attributes: titleAttributes)
            txtEditor.attributedText = titleString
```

after this code i want to write in (real time) with  uitextview but in **Black Color**
for example in this function i need to write

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

return true
    }
```

How can i write in other color in continue of  this textView

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423632/how-to-allow-nsattributedstring-text-be-typed-into-a-uitextview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow NSAttributedString text be typed into a UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423632/how-to-allow-nsattributedstring-text-be-typed-into-a-uitextview)

Answer (score 1):

To configure the color in which the user will type, set the text view’s typing attributes.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618629-typingattributes

Comment: , hello can you give me some example , and is that the old text stay in purpol ?

Comment: but in first time the textview it was default after typing 2 or 1 character it will be normal

Comment: You need to set it again every time the user types.